# SQL Server 2008 R2 - convert all datetime parts (as ints) into a datetime column

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, integer, concatenation

I have a table that has the datetime pieces (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond) stored as integers. I'd like to concatenate them into a single `datetime` column.

I've tried various approaches but none work - there seems to be no simple way to put these items together?

Comment: If you could upgrade to SQL Server **2012** or newer, you could use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s  actually, `datetimefromparts`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: absolutely right - the heat is getting to my brain, it seems :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each part to a varchar and concatenate them together in the format of an ISO datetime string. Then use [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert the string to a  [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Here is an example. You would need to replace each hard coded integer with the name of the column from your table.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(2016 AS VARCHAR(4)) -- year
    + '-' + CAST('0' + CAST(8 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)) -- month
    + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(13 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- day of month
    + 'T' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(16 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- hours (I assume its military time (24 hours))
    + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(32 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- minutes
    + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(07 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- seconds
    + '.' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(64 AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)) AS MyDate -- milliseconds
FROM yourTable
```

Or with column names (assumed)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(yt.Year AS VARCHAR(4)) -- year
    + '-' + CAST('0' + CAST(yt.Month AS VARCHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)) -- month
    + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(yt.Day AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- day of month
    + 'T' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(yt.Hours AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- hours (I assume its military time (24 hours))
    + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(yt.Minutes AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- minutes
    + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(yt.Seconds AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) -- seconds
    + '.' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(yt.Milliseconds AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)) AS MyDate -- milliseconds
FROM yourTable yt
```

One more note. Microsoft recommends that you use [DateTime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) instead of [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) to persist date time values starting with Sql Server 2008 (which you tagged in your question).

Comment: You need to use `T` as the separator to create an ISO 8601 datetime string. Otherwise SQL Server will try to parse the string as locale specific

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thank you, I corrected my answer.

Comment: This worked well - thank you!  I had to hack up my millisecond value a bit as mine were 6 digits long and the datetime datatype expects three digits.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Prior to sql server 2012, you can use a series of nested [`DATEADD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) functions to mimic [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) function

Create and populate sample data (In your next question, please save us this step)

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    cYear int,
    cMonth int,
    cDay int,
    cHour int,
    cMinute int,
    cSecond int,
    cMillisecond int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2016, 6, 22, 16, 34, 25, 3)
```

The query:

```
SELECT *,
        DATEADD(MILLISECOND, cMillisecond, 
            DATEADD(SECOND, cSecond, 
                DATEADD(MINUTE, cMinute, 
                    DATEADD(HOUR, cHour, 
                        DATEADD(DAY, cDay -1, 
                            DATEADD(MONTH, cMonth - 1, 
                                DATEADD(YEAR, cYear - 2000, '2000-01-01')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ) As TheDate
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
cYear   cMonth   cDay   cHour   cMinute   cSecond   cMillisecond TheDate
-----   ------   ----   -----   -------  -------   ------------- -----------------------
2016    6        22     16      34        25        3            2016-06-22 16:34:25.003
```

Note that the base date I'm using is January 1st 2000, therefor you need to subtract 2000 from the year, 1 from the month and 1 from the days.

Comment: Thank you!  I went with the second answer but I can see the value in yours, too.  Thanks!